# Pandas data frame throw > exception: no description

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, tf-idf

> I want print document by term matrice. Working without problems in
>   small documents. For example, 10000 documents But 25000 documents
>   throw error

---

### System Information

```
  Time of this report: 4/23/2019, 21:08:52
         Machine name: DESKTOP-71B1MM1
           Machine Id: {D2C93244-A7B3-49EC-8F35-AC173B92F828}
     Operating System: Windows 10 Pro 64-bit (10.0, Build 17763) (17763.rs5_release.180914-1434)
             Language: Turkish (Regional Setting: Turkish)
  System Manufacturer: FUJITSU
         System Model: ESPRIMO P420
                 BIOS: V4.6.5.4 R1.46.0 for D3230-A1x (type: UEFI)
            Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4570 CPU @ 3.20GHz (4 CPUs), ~3.2GHz
               Memory: 16384MB RAM
  Available OS Memory: 16318MB RAM
            Page File: 11041MB used, 52340MB available
          Windows Dir: C:\WINDOWS
      DirectX Version: DirectX 12
  DX Setup Parameters: Not found
     User DPI Setting: 120 DPI (125 percent)
   System DPI Setting: 96 DPI (100 percent)
      DWM DPI Scaling: Disabled
             Miracast: Available, with HDCP




  from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
  Tfidf_Vector = TfidfVectorizer(min_df = 0., max_df = 1., use_idf = True)
  Tfidf_Matrix = Tfidf_Vector.fit_transform(normalized_documents.ravel())
  Tfidf_Matrix = Tfidf_Matrix.toarray()
  features = Tfidf_Vector.get_feature_names()
  Tfidf_df = pd.DataFrame(np.round(Tfidf_Matrix, 3), columns = features)
```

[image: Throw Error img]

Comment: You can report it as an issue in the pandas git repo: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues